# Regex: How to get regex matches to overlap?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, match

I have a string formatted as follows:

`'0 = text defining value 1 = text2 2 = text3, text3 (text3) 3 = text4'`

with an unknown number of values. I'm trying to get a regex to match the 0 and 'text defining value' together for each number description pair. Right now, I have

`'([0-9]{1,2}) ?= ?(.*?) ?[0-9]{0,2} ?[=$]'`

as my regex, but this only matches to every other value in the field. Any suggestions on how to get it to match to all of them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lookahead to figure out where the next partition is:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(\d+)\s+=\s+(.*?)(?=\s+\d+\s+|$)")

your_text = "0 = text defining value 1 = text2 2 = text3, text3 (text3) 3 = text4"

pairs = pattern.findall(your_text)
# [('0', 'text defining value'),
#  ('1', 'text2'),
#  ('2', 'text3, text3 (text3)'),
#  ('3', 'text4')]
```

If that's what you're looking for, your question is a bit murky.

Comment: Thanks! sorry about the murkiness, I'm really new to regex and haven't really learned the correct nomenclature for everything. This will work for what I need, thanks!